# Orbit of $SO_r$ in $SL_r$

Tags: linear-algebra

Take the action of the special orthogonal group on the speciale linear group by left multiplication, over $\mathbb C$, how could one identify the quotient space?

Thanks

Comment: Isn't that simply the symmetric space $K\backslash G = Y$?

Comment: I would sugest to use dimensions, but this may not work I think, @Asaf, I don't see what your notations mean?

Comment: The map $A\mapsto A^TA$ identifies $SL_r/SO_r$ with the space of $r\tm r$ positive definite symmetric matrices of determinant one.

Comment: In what terms would you like an answer?  The quotient is a smooth, rational, affine complex variety of dimension $(r^2+r-2)/2$.  The quotient is naturally a parameter space for smooth quadric hypersurfaces in $\mathbb{P}^{r-1}$, thus it is the open affine complement of a discriminant hypersurface of degree $r$ in the projective space of dimension $(r^2+r-2)/2$.

Comment: @NeilStrickland: I think you are giving more than the OP asked.  The OP just asked for the description over $\mathbb{C}$, but it looks like you are giving a description of a real form.

Comment: Over $\mathbb C$, this is just the space of nondegenerate quadratic forms in $n$ variables with discriminant one

Comment: @Venkataramana Just a remark here, the action is not by conjugation but just by left multiplication, does that change any thing?

Comment: No, it does not. I do not know how to describe the quotient under the conjugation action. The identification I am talking about is $g\mapsto Q=^t g g$ which maps $SO(r)\backslash SL_r$ into discriminant one non-degenerate quadratic forms.

Comment: Strickland and Venkataramana are both correct: my description is off.  The affine variety I describe is the quotient of $\textbf{SL}_r$ by the slightly larger subgroup $Z(\textbf{SL}_r)\textbf{SO}_r$ that contains $\textbf{SO}_r$ as a normal subgroup (the connected component) of index $r$ (when $r$ is odd) or $r/2$ (when $r$ is even).

Answer (score 2):

The quotient space $SO_r\backslash SL_r$ is canonically identified with a closed subvarity of the space $$Sym^2(V^*\otimes V^*)$$
 (where $V$ is a vector space of dimension $r$)
which can be seen as the subspace of symmetric matrices of determinant equal to $1$, which is again the space of non degenerate quadratic forms with determinant $1$, In fact, $SL_r$ act transitively (by conjugation) on $$Sym^2(V^*\otimes V^*)_1$$ (det=1 part), and the isotropy at any point is isomorphic to $SO_r$.

Comment: the restriction of this action to $SO_r$ is NOT trivial. the group $SO_r$ has a fixed point, that is all.

Comment: yes exactly I have confused the two morphisms!